# (Android) Buttons Inside Every Gridview Row Problem With Focusability

Tags: android, button, gridview

Good day to everyone.

My question : i have a button inside my gridview item layout and a custom adapter for it now on a touch screen it all works perfectly but i am trying to adapt my application for android TV's and other android remote controlled devices like firestick etc but when scrolling through my gridview the selector (android:listSelector="@color/colorAccent") is highlighting the whole row where as i want to be able to maybe press left while the row is highlighted and it will change the listselector to highlight the button inside that row.. here is what my xml looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgbtnDemo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" >
        </ImageButton>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my gridview in the mainactivity.xml

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridSources"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:listSelector="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Any help would be appreciated Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:padding="5dp" >
```

Comment: added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" and same results works okay on touch devices but cant select the button on tv device with dpad remote?? there has to be a way i been trying for days now lol..

Comment: Set a tag for the button and inside onclick listener use if condition to validate the tag name, thereby you can get rid of the issue.

Comment: yeah thats not the issue here i want to be able to highlight/changethe color of the button inside each gridview row when it is focused or selected but the button will not gain focus or select with dpad although everything works fine on touch device?

Comment: Please refer to " Modifying directional navigation " for Dpad left key in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation)